# Нужно ли ставить запятые? (2)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нужны ли запятые в предложении?

> Однако из-за плохой сохранности фондов архива непрерывная поколенная
> роспись начинается с Петра Истратова.

Comment: Александр, у Вас остались ещё какие-то вопросы по данной теме? Спрашивайте, порассуждаем дальше. Вы почему-то перестали принимать ответы...

Comment: Александр, вопросов по данной теме нет, ответ исчерпывающий.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Обособление обстоятельственных оборотов факультативно (см. [**Обстоятельства, выраженные существительными**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=114), Розенталь) и зависит от множества факторов, в том числе интонации, контекста, структуры предложения, поэтому возможны варианты.

Несмотря на то что в предложении есть произносительная пауза, я бы оставил его без запятых:

***Однако из-за плохой сохранности фондов архива // непрерывная поколенная роспись начинается с Петра Истратова.***

При изменении структуры запятые ставились бы:

*Однако непрерывная поколенная роспись, **из-за плохой сохранности фондов архива,** начинается с Петра Истратова.*

«Однако» тоже не требует обособления:

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка** ([Грамота.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%5C_))

> Согласно справочникам, слово ***однако*** в начале предложения не является вводным, имеет значение противительного союза и не выделяется запятыми.

См. также: [**ОДНАКО (ЖЕ / Ж),**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_504) *вводное слово, союз, междометие*.

Comment: Вот, думаю, подходящий пример (с поддержкой ответа): *Однако из-за плохой сохранности и значительных лакун в комплектности они относятся к числу самых труднодоступных для исследователей.* (http://www.bfrz.ru/?mod=news&id=1588)

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Большое спасибо, Римма!

Comment: "Щас-щас", Саша! Закрутилась маленько и отвлеклась чуть. У нас ведь несказанный праздник. Поделюсь радостью (помните детские вопросы?): *наша* любопытная девочка два дня назад стала чемпионкой Эстонии!

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова  Ух ты! Вот это здорово! Вы говорили, что она спортсменка. Интересно, в каком спорте.

Comment: Художественная гимнастика.